# Unable to parse date?

Tags: android, date

I am Trying Parse Date string to Date but unable to parse . it showing some exceptions

Code

```
Date date = null;
String dtStart = "2013-11-08 05:46:55" ;  
SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");  
try {  
    date = format.parse(dtStart);  
    System.out.println("Date ->"+date);  
} catch (ParseException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Stacktace:

```
11-08 19:04:06.394: W/System.err(8659): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-11-08 05:46:55"
11-08 19:04:06.402: W/System.err(8659):     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:626)
```

Please give some solutions

Comment: try this 
`SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
date = format.parse(dtStart);  
//Output it as a string that uses the new format
SimpleDateFormat newFormat_date= new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMMMMMMM yyyy"); 

if (date!=null) {
String desiredDateFormat = newFormat_date.format(date);
holder.posted_on_date.setText(desiredDateFormat);
holder.posted_on_date.setTypeface(tf2);
}else{
holder.posted_on_date.setText("N/A");
}`

Comment: your simple date format should be like this. SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); as your date is in this format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change like this..you will get the date..

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
date = format.parse(dtStart);  
//Output it as a string that uses the new format
SimpleDateFormat newFormat_date= new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMMMMMMM yyyy"); 

if (date!=null) {
String desiredDateFormat = newFormat_date.format(date);
holder.posted_on_date.setText(desiredDateFormat);
}else{
holder.posted_on_date.setText("N/A");
}
```